# Chrome iframe parent is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have this script for Gmail. It runs inside the `canvas_frame` iframe.
I want to get a handle to the parent document, using `parent.document`. But in Chrome tells me that it's undefined. Works fine in Firefox, but blows up on Chrome.
So how exactly do I get a handle to the parent document, from within an iframe, in Chrome.
Chrome ver: 11.0.686.3

Here's the code that's failing:

```
function init() {
    try {
        if(parent == null) {
            console.log(typeof parent);
            window.setTimeout(init, 200);
            return;
        }
        // SOME MORE STUFF
    } catch(e) { console.log(e) }
}
```

This part just outputs `undefined` endlessly in the log window.
Here's a test script that produces the same result. It outputs `undefined` followed by `cQ` endlessly.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           TEST SCRIPT FOR CHROME
// @version        1.0
// @namespace      1nfected
// @description    TEST
// @include        http://mail.google.com/*
// @include        https://mail.google.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
if(document.documentElement.className != 'cQ') {
    console.log('not our frame');
    return;
}
function init() {
    if(window.parent == null) {
        console.log(typeof window.parent);
        console.log(document.documentElement.className);
        window.setTimeout(init, 1000);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Found the parent');
}
init();
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realised that in Google Chrome, userscripts are denied access to `window.parent` .
It would only work if I injected the script into the webpage.

Comment: Thats why I said User Scripts in Chrome are limited, using a Content Script will be better since you got the total control (kinda).

Comment: I did a little reading and eventually did find an issue filed at code.google.com regarding this. I don't think a content script would be any good either.

Answer (score 4):

UserScripts in Chrome are limited, especially when it comes to iframes.

Any reason why you can't do it the other way? For instance:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('canvas_frame');
if (frame) {
  var dom = frame.contentDocument;
}
```

The better answer here would be [Chrome Extensions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html), you would have more control with a [Content Script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) instead of a User Script.

Comment: That's how i've been doing it up until now. But since a few days, that method has been playing up. the dom (frame.contentDocument) object wouldn't return me anything. When i switched to the method i'm currently after, it started working 100% again, but only in firefox unfortunately. Haven't tested Opera yet.

Comment: If it is acting up, please submit a bug report and place a small reduced test case. Since I am Chromium contributor, I will triage it and assign it to proper devs.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might be the issue filed in this regard: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20773