# In Chrome, can't access any variables or functions of a child iframe, or of an iframe's parent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, parent

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211101/chrome-iframe-parent-is-undefined), although a bit broader.

I'm just opening these pages locally, and they sit in the same folder.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>TestIndex</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init()
            {
                alert("child.childvar: " + child.childvar); //works in FF, IE, not Chrome
                alert("frames['child'].childvar: " + frames['child'].childvar); //works in FF, IE, not Chrome
                alert("document.getElementById('child').contentWindow['childvar']: " + document.getElementById('child').contentWindow['childvar']); //works in FF, IE, not Chrome

                child.childfunc(); //works in FF, IE, not Chrome
                frames['child'].childfunc(); //works in FF, IE, not Chrome
                document.getElementById('child').contentWindow['childfunc()']; //doesn't work in anything
            }

            var parentvar = 7;
            function parentfunc()
            {
                alert("In parentfunc");
            }
            window.onload = init;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe id="child" name="child" src="child.html">Your browser does not support iframes</iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

child.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>TestChild</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function init()
            {
                alert("parent.parentvar: " + parent.parentvar); //works in FF, IE, not Chrome

                parent.parentfunc(); //works in FF, IE, not Chrome
            }

            var childvar = 5;
            function childfunc()
            {
                alert("In childfunc");
            }
            window.onload = init;
        </script>
    </head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to achieve any communication at all between a page and its iframe's content in chrome. I did read the answers to the question I linked to, but I don't really know what userscripts/content scripts are, so I don't know how relevant that questions was to mine.

I guess my actual question is: how the hell do I get values from an iframe'd page into the parent page!?

Comment: Wooo,tumbleweed! For what it's worth, I've logged this as an issue here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=79127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently javascript inter-frame communication doesn't work when on the local file system.  Put the files on a server and it will likely function as expected.

Comment: How did you find this out? Don't have time to test this at the moment (been moved on to a new project), but I'll give it a go at some stage, out of curiosity.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Sorry it took me so long to test and accept this!